# OpenLayers, Geoserver: TileWMS are displaying wrong

Tags: openlayers, wms, tiles

I'm trying to display some WMS with tiles, but at every zoom (in or out) the images are displaying wrong, with wrong proportions. This is how I'm creating the tile:

```
    var map = this.state.map;
    var layers =
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                url: 'http://XX.XX.XX:8080/geoserver/cite/wms',
                params: {'LAYERS': 'cite:clientes_ex', 'TILED': true, 'VERSION': '1.3.0',
                    'FORMAT': 'image/png8', 'WIDTH': 256, 'HEIGHT': 256, 'CRS': 'EPSG:3857'},
                serverType: 'geoserver'
            })
        })
    map.addLayer(layers);
```

This is what happens.
[image]

This is another example, in zooms very far way from the map:
[image]

Any idea how could I fix it?

Comment: I have the similar problem when using map projection: 'EPSG:3035'. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skZHj.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skZHj.jpg)
But tiles displays in correct order with map projection: 'EPSG:3857'.
Any reason why is that happening?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/119428)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/119428)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/119428)